# FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-value-(oob-code),-starting-an-object-on-a-scalar-field)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting an error on the oob-code given by firebase, **`FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-value-(oob-code),-starting-an-object-on-a-scalar-field).`**.

This is happening on my reset password function, as I customised my own reset password page instead of using firebase default.

Here are my code, I followed the code on firebase documentation closely but my error comes in at the `auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(auth, actionCode).then((email) => {` line shown below.

```
    const handleResetPassword = () => {
        // Verify the password reset code is valid.
        try {
            console.log(actionCode)
            auth.verifyPasswordResetCode(auth, actionCode).then((email) => {
                console.log("got in")
                console.log(email)
                const accountEmail = email;

                // Save the new password.
                auth.confirmPasswordReset(auth, actionCode, values.newPassword).then((resp) => {
                    // Password reset has been confirmed and new password updated.
                    console.log(resp);

                    login(accountEmail, values.newPassword)
                        .then((flag) => {
                            if (flag.includes('ERROR')) {
                                setMessage(flag)
                            }
                        })
                        .catch((e) => {
                            console.log(e);
                            setMessage("Something went wrong")
                        })
                    // TODO: Display a link back to the app, or sign-in the user directly
                    // if the page belongs to the same domain as the app:
                    // auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(accountEmail, newPassword);

                    // TODO: If a continue URL is available, display a button which on
                    // click redirects the user back to the app via continueUrl with
                    // additional state determined from that URL's parameters.
                }).catch((error) => {
                    // Error occurred during confirmation. The code might have expired or the
                    // password is too weak.
                    console.log(error)
                });
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error)
                // Invalid or expired action code. Ask user to try to reset the password
                // again.
            });

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

Here is the console log output for the error.
[image: Console Output Error]

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I used the imported functions instead of the app auth.

```
import { verifyPasswordResetCode, confirmPasswordReset } from "firebase/auth";

verifyPasswordResetCode(auth, actionCode).then((email) => {
                ....
                confirmPasswordReset(auth, actionCode, values.newPassword).then((resp) => {
                                 ...
```